# MySQL Errors - You must SET PASSWORD/Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number

Tags: mysql, mediawiki

All, this is probably a simple fix but I can't seem to get it working...

I'm trying to set up a MySQL database (on RHEL) but getting the following errors:

```
mysql> SELECT 1;
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_pass');
ERROR 1372 (HY000): Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number
mysql> SELECT PASSWORD('new_pass');
ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement
```

I've tried every possible command/query and I cannot bypass these two error messages. Maybe something's up with my permissions? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Did you think of checking the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) for the proper syntax?

Comment: Run this before setting the password `SET old_passwords = 0;`

Answer (score 12):

if you want to change the password of mysql, you should use the command code as below,

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('New_Password');
```

Comment: This way worked for me

Answer (score 7):

use this `SET old_passwords = 0;`

> The old_passwords system variable value determines the hashing method
>   used by PASSWORD(). If SET PASSWORD rejects the password as not being
>   in the correct format, it may be necessary to change old_passwords to
>   change the hashing method. For example, if the account uses the
>   mysql_native_password plugin, the old_passwords value must be 0:
>
> SET old_passwords = 0; 
>   SET PASSWORD FOR 'jeffrey'@'localhost' =
>   PASSWORD('mypass'); If the old_passwords value differs from that
>   required by the authentication plugin, the hashed password value
>   returned by PASSWORD() is not acceptable for that plugin, and attempts
>   to set the password produce an error. For example:
>
> mysql> SET old_passwords = 1; 
>   mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR
>   'jeffrey'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('mypass'); ERROR 1372 (HY000):
>   Password hash should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number Permitted
>   old_passwords values are described later in this section.
>
> Using the OLD_PASSWORD() function (permitted before MySQL 5.7.5 only):